# Python Nested For-loop Multiplication Table Must Have Exact Output of Teacher

Tags: python, multiplication

Have a school project that I just can't seem to crack. I need to create a python multiplication table using for-loops and nested for loops. I have the code to create the table but the problem is that I have to copy the exact output that my teacher got when he made the program. His output:[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFvjf.png). 
My current code looks like this:

```
n = 12

print("*\t|", end = "\t")

for i in range(1, 13):
    print(i, end = "\t")

print()

for i in range(1, 112):
    print("=", end = "")

print()

for i in range(1, 13, 1):
    print(i, "\t|")

for row in range(1, n + 1):
    for col in range(1, n+1):
        print(row * col, end = "\t")
    print()
```

Any help would be much appreciated (sorry for any bad formatting this is my first post!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge the code for the `i` loop and the `row` loop:

```
for row in range(1, n + 1):
    print(row, "\t|", end = "\t")
    for col in range(1, n+1):
        print(row * col, end = "\t")
    print()
```

Also, you might replace your `13` everywhere with `n+1` for consistency, if you haven't already done that.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the corrected code:

```
n = 12

print("*\t|", end = "\t")

for i in range(1, 13):
    print(i, end = "\t")

print()

for i in range(1, 55):
    print("=", end = "")

print()

for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    print(i, end="\t|\t")

    for col  in range(1, 13):
        print(i * col, end="\t")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(1, 13):
        print("*", i, ":", end=" ")
        for j in range(1, 13):
            print("{:2d}".format(i * j), end=" ")
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]print()
```

[image]